# Python descriptors with arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators, descriptor

TL;DR
Python 2.7.5, when using descriptors as decorators, is there any way to pass in arguments (to the `__init__` method)?
OR
How can I get access to a class instance's attributes using a method decorator with arguments ([as here](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845))? -- I believe this is not possible, though, hence the focus below on descriptors...

---

Long version

I have a class of objects, with different "type" attributes. Based on an instance's "type", I would like a method to be available or not. I know one way is to create multiple classes, but I'm trying to not have a bunch of if / else statements when creating these objects. For example, I have two objects A and B that are almost identical, except object B I don't want to have the `get_start_date()` method available. So essentially, what I want is that both A and B are instances of class MyObjects, but have a "type" attribute that is different.

```
type(A) == type(B)
A.genus_type != B.genus_type
```

I would use that `.genus_type` attribute to differentiate which methods are allowable and which ones not...

I was thinking I could use decorators with a whitelist, like:

```
def valid_for(whitelist):
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
return wrap

class A(object):
    @valid_for(['typeB'])
    def do_something_cool(self):
        print 'blah'
```

But the problem was I did not have access to the actual class instance in the decorator, where I could test for the instance type attribute. Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366713/can-a-python-decorator-of-an-instance-method-access-the-class), I thought, "I can use descriptors!".

So I then tried:

```
class valid_for(object):
    """ descriptor to check the type of an item, to see
    if the method is valid for that type"""
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.f = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        def wrapper(*args):
            return self.f(instance, *args)
        return wrapper
```

But then I couldn't figure out how to get the `['typeB']` parameter passed into the descriptor...by default, Python passes in the called method as the argument to `__init__`. I could create hard-coded descriptors for each type and nest them, but then I wonder if I will run into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581288/nesting-descriptors-decorators-in-python). Assuming I could overcome the nesting issue, it also seems less clean to do something like:

```
class A(object):
    @valid_for_type_b
    @valid_for_type_f
    @valid_for_type_g
    def do_something_cool(self):
        print 'blah'
```

Doing something like this just made my `func` equal to the list `['typeB']`...

```
class valid_for(object):
    """ descriptor to check the type of an item, to see
    if the method is valid for that type"""
    def __init__(self, func, *args):
        self.f = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        def wrapper(*args):
            return self.f(instance, *args)
        return wrapper

class A(object):
    @valid_for(['typeB'])
    def do_something_cool(self):
        print 'blah'
```

And my `func` is not in the `*args` list, so I can't just do a simple swap of arguments (`*args` is empty).

I've been looking for hints [here](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), but haven't found anything that seems like a clean or valid workaround. Is there a clean way to do this, or do I have to use multiple classes and just mix-in the various methods? Or, right now I am leaning towards an instance method that checks, but that seems less clean and reusable...

```
class A(object):
    def _valid_for(self, whitelist):
        if self.genus_type not in whitelist:
            raise Exception

    def do_something_cool(self):
        self._valid_for(['foo'])
        print 'blah'
```

I am using Python 2.7.5.

---

UPDATE 1

Per a suggestion in the comments, I tried:

```
def valid_for2(whitelist):
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            import pdb
            pdb.set_trace()
            print args[0].genus_type
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return wrap
```

But at this point, args[0]. just returns the args:

```
(Pdb) args[0]
args = (<FormRecord object at 0x112f824d0>,)
kwargs = {}
(Pdb) args[0].genus_type
args = (<FormRecord object at 0x112f824d0>,)
kwargs = {}
```

However, using `functools` as suggested does work -- so I will award the answer. There seems to be some black magic in `functools` that lets the arguments in?

---

UPDATE 2

So investigating jonrsharpe's suggestion more, his method also seems to work, but I have to explicitly use `self` instead of `args[0]`. Not sure why the behavior is different...

```
def valid_for2(whitelist):
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print self.genus_type
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return wrap
```

results in the same output as with `functools`.
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I tried with decorators -- but with a decorator, I believe I cannot get access to that class instance's attributes...

Comment: Surely the biggest problem is that, when you're decorating the method, you don't have access to the class the method is in? You can get access to `self` (and therefore test `isinstance(self, ...)` or `type(self)`) in `wrapper` (it's currently `args[0]`, but you could make it explicit), but you can't include the class that's currently being defined in `whitelist`. How will you resolve `'typeB'` to the actual class?

Comment: So my terminology  might be confusing. When I use 'typeB' as an example above, it is defined as an attribute on the class instance -- like B.genus_type = 'typeB'. I'm hoping everything can be a single class, so type(A) == type(B), but A.genus_type != B.genus_type.

Comment: So why don't you just check e.g. `args[0].genus_type in whitelist` inside `wrapper`?

Comment: Mmm, so I'm not knowledgeable enough about why that doesn't work, but I'll paste the result above. Basically it just returns the arg list?

Comment: Okay, in reply to @jonrsharpe, it's funny, but what you suggested works when I explicitly use `self` instead of `args[0]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, what you are looking for is [a
closure](http://effbot.org/zone/closure.htm) -- a function that can refer to
the local namespace of an outer function.

Since you are passing `['typeB']` to `valid_for`, as in

```
@valid_for(['typeB'])
```

we should make `valid_for` a *function* that returns a decorator.
The decorator in turn accepts a function (the nascent method) as input and returns another (`wrapper`) function.

Below `wrapper` is a closure which can access the value of `typelist` from
within its body at runtime.

---

```
import functools
def valid_for(typelist):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(self, *args):
            if self.genus_type in typelist:
                return func(self, *args)
            else:
                # handle this case
                raise NotImplementedError(
                    '{} not in {}'.format(self.genus_type, typelist))
        return wrapper
    return decorator

class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.genus_type = 'typeA'
    @valid_for(['typeB'])
    def do_something_cool(self):
        print 'blah'

a = A()
try:
    a.do_something_cool()
except NotImplementedError as err:
    print(err)
    # typeA not in ['typeB']

a.genus_type = 'typeB'
a.do_something_cool()
# blah
```